# How to Place an Image Behind A Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I have 4 Tablices, there are always exactly two cells of data for each tablix, so there are only 8 Fields of data in total.

My problem: when i try to place an Image behind those tablices the Tablices are rendered under the report, so in the upper portion of the report is my image and on the next page there are my tablices. how can i set it up in a way that the image stays behind the tablices?

i already tried to rightclick on the image -> send to back on the design view the report looks like i intend, with the placeholders and headers exactly on top of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the tablices inside a rectangle (cut and paste, to make sure that the rectangle is the parent of the tablices), and then place that rectangle on top of the image.

Comment: At first this approach did not work but then i set the background image of that rectangle to the image i wanted, and that worked! thx!